# Gradle plugin as part of multi-project source tree

Tags: gradle

There's a big multi-project source tree. I need to define a gradle plugin as a part of this source tree and use it  by `gradle build` without needing `gradle install`. Is such a thing possible?

Ideally the structure should look like:

```
<root>
   +- my_plugin/
   |    ...
   +- module1/
      +- build.gradle # apply plugin: '<mypluginid>'
```

and simple `gradle build` should be enough.